sectional curvature is the value of a function, then the function is constant
$(M^n,g)$ connected Riemannian manifold with $n\ge 3$ (why the dimension?) s.t. there is a function $f\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$ s.t. $K(\sigma)=f(p)$ for all 2-dim subspace $\sigma\subset T_pM$. Show that $f$ must be constant function on $M$.
Attempt
We know that $R(x,y,z,w)=<R(x,y)z,w>=f(p)(<x,w><y,z>-<x,z><y,w>)$
Also, if we denote by $R'=<x,w><y,z>-<x,z><y,w>$ we have that $\nabla R'=0$ which is easy to see:
$\nabla_Z <x,y>=Z\cdot<x,y>-<\nabla_Z x,y>-<x,\nabla_Z y>=0$, since $\nabla$ is compatible with the metric. Also, if we denote $T=<\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot>=<\cdot,\cdot>\cdot<\cdot,\cdot>$ we also have $\nabla T=0$.
So, $\nabla_u R(x,y,z,w)=df(u)R'(x,y,z,w)$. How can I continue from here?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma_(Riemannian_geometry)#:~:text=In%20Riemannian%20geometry%2C%20Schur's%20lemma,forced%20to%20be%20globally%20constant.
